# when is $(5a^2-3)(a^2+1)$ a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Are there any other integers a such that

$(5a^2-3)(a^2+1)$ is a perfect square

than $-7, -1, 1,7$  and if possible to find what are these integers. By checking on wolfram it says that they are the only one but i doubt wolfram is always correct in diophantines . I think that both terms in the product are of form $2x^2$  but after can't make much progress

Comment: See [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266364543_A_simple_method_for_solving_the_diophantine_equation_Y_2_X_4_aX_3_bX_2_cXd).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think they assume the polynomial is monic?

Comment: The general situation is discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701700/seeking-general-methods-to-attack-ax4bx3ycx2y2dxy3ey4-z2-in-integer), for $y=1$.

Comment: Actually, your equation is $Y^2=aX^4+bX^2+c$, which is discussed [here](https://shrek.unideb.hu/~tengely/near2.pdf), for example.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Thanks for ur time but i am afraid I might not be able to understand that

Comment: What's the final answer though? Does it have others, if u know

Comment: If it is from a contest, then these are the only solutions, and you probably can prove this with [this strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884100/find-all-value-of-integers-n-for-which-the-expression-is-a-perfect-square).

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's not from a math contest I actually observed this when solving another problem. The thing with that approach is the leading coefficient has to be a perfect square

Comment: This one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814149/sum-of-integers-sum-of-their-reciprocals-special-case

Comment: Maybe we should switch ideas to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ being an UFD then $a^2+1=(a+i)(a-i)$ however $5a^2-3$ can't be factorized maybe we can still have some progress

Comment: My idea was, to use what you said, namely $a^2+1=2u^2$ and $5a^2-3=2v^2$.  We have two Pell equations $a^2-2u^2=-1$ and $5a^2-2v^2=3$. They do not have simultaneous solutions except for $a=\pm 1,\pm 7$.

Comment: Ya i have also tried that but i wasent able to show that coz the second equation isn't really a nice pells equation

Comment: But it is. One recursive solution of $5x^2-2y^2=3$ is given by $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$ and $x_{n+1}=19x_n+12y_n$, $y_{n+1}=30x_n+19y_n$. So $(1,1),(31,49),(1177,1861),\ldots $.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I thought u meant to use a closed form

Comment: But lets see if u can make progress with that